# php response body as object array, how to parse the content

Tags: php, arrays, httpresponse

one of the API return response as object array, I json encode the object array as below

```
{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","detail":"Missing required parameter.","field":"amount_money.amount"}]}
```

I want to get the **detail** field value, how to get it.

Comment: Why do you encode a response to JSON?

Comment: @Daan to read the content, otherwise it look like Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [category] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR [code] => MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER [detail] => Missing required parameter. [field] => amount_money.amount ) ) )

Comment: If the API returns an object array, why not just get the `detail` field from that object array?

Comment: @AbleAlias Isn't the array/object not what you want then? If you want detail value don't encode it to JSON.

Comment: I want to get the "detail" field value to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `detail` field right away from response array.

```
<?php
$json = '{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","detail":"Missing required parameter.","field":"amount_money.amount"}]}';
```

I'm converting your `JSON` to `Array` just for example.

```
//Actual Array Response
$a = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";

//Save detail to Variable
$detail = $a['errors'][0]['detail'];
echo $detail;
?>
```

Comment: I don't think the response is in PHP.

Comment: He's tagged the question as PHP, as well as in the page title.

Comment: @Daan OP mentioned only `php`, `arrays` in tags

Comment: Hi Thanks, I was tying $a['errors'][0]->detail, this works.

Comment: @Marcus My bad didn't look at the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Use dot-notation to access object elements:

```js
     // if that response is as string JSON
    var obj = JSON.parse('{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","detail":"Missing required parameter.","field":"amount_money.amount"}]}');

    alert("Details is: "+obj.errors[0].detail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array structure is:

```
array (size=1)
  'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'category' => string 'INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR' (length=21)
          'code' => string 'MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER' (length=26)
          'detail' => string 'Missing required parameter.' (length=27)
          'field' => string 'amount_money.amount' (length=19)
```

So to get to the bottom you can get it like this:

```
$array = json_decode('{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","detail":"Missing required parameter.","field":"amount_money.amount"}]}',true);    
echo $array['errors'][0]['detail'];
```

Answer (score 0):

(pseudo)

```
$response = Array (
    [errors] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [category] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR
            [code] => MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER
            [detail] => Missing required parameter.
            [field] => amount_money.amount
        )
    )
)
```

To directly access (and *not* encode to JSON) *detail* you would simply use (something like) the following:

```
$response['errors'][0]->detail
```

Obviously where `$response` is holding the array in question. Might differ in your script.

Then you assign that value to a variable `$detail = $response['errors'][0]->detail;`, or simply output it `echo $response['errors'][0]->detail;` Whatever you like.

Comment: I tried this, but this is not working, but this works $a['errors'][0]['detail']

Comment: This code works when you are accessing the response directly from the API. There is no need to encode the response to JSON, only to decode it immediately following like other answers. If the response comes as an array/object, just deal with it in that manner.